# Nmap ICMP Request with IP Options

Tags: nmap

Just need to put the "router alert" option in a Ping Request.

Router Alert is 0x94040000 at the end of the IP header.

This is what I've tried (and a lot of other variations):

```
sudo nmap -sU -PE --ip-options "\x94\x04\x00\x00" 15.234.166.241
```

`nmap` man page says that "-PE" will send ICMP Echo Request, but all I see in the wireshark trace is TCP activity.

So in summary: I need to send a normal ICMP Echo Request with the Router Alert option in the IP header.  So far, nmap has been a struggle.  I'm open to other ideas -but according to nmap manuals and man-pages, this should have been easy.

Prefer not to build/compile any new ping commands nor change ubuntu kernel code.

Answer (score 1):

`nping` had what I needed:

```
sudo nping -icmp -c 1 -icmp-type 8 --ip-options "\x94\x04\x00\x00" -dest-ip 192.168.1.5
```